# Regex repetitions

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I would like to use regex to find chapter numberings.
If I have following string, I would like to filter out 3. Results and 3.1. Result without 5. being removed.

```
import re
MyStr = """ test 5.

3. Results

3.1. Result 2

3.3.1 Result

test test test test"""

print(repr(MyStr))
match = re.findall(r"(?:\d[ \t]*?).+?\n\n", MyStr, re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
print(match)
```

However, I can't differentiate between test 5. and 3.
THe questions: How do I tell regex to that the . cannot be followed by \n but only for the first following character. I tried adding [ \t] in many different ways but without success. The regex should still be flexible enough to filter out any forms of 3.

Your kind help is appreciated.

Stijn

Comment: Anchor your regexp to the start of the line `r"^(?...`?

Comment: I tried this but does not work.

Comment: that's because you're using re.MULTILINE

Comment: Negative. This does not resolve the problem. Plus the multiline is required if the line is longer than one line.

Comment: How about `match = re.findall(r"^(?:\d\.?)+.+\n\n", MyStr, re.MULTILINE)` ?

Comment: Negative. the DOTALL is required to find any spaces in the chapter title e.g. 3.1. Why I need spaces!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure of the restraints of your numbering system. Anyway, the code below, applied to your example, works for me:

```
import re

MyStr = """ test 5.

3. Results

3.1. Result 2

3.3.1 Result

test test test test"""

str_list = re.findall(r'^(?:\d+\.)+.*?$', MyStr, re.MULTILINE)
for s in str_list:
    print(s)
```

Here is an improved version, able to handle all the cases in the modified table of contents.

```
import re

MyStr = """Table of Contents ...

1. 1st title

20. 1-line title

300. 2-lines title ...
   ... continued here

300.1. 1-line subtitle

300.2. 2-lines subtitle ...
   ... continued here

300.3.1 title, not followed by a blank line
300.3.20 next title omitted and no trailing period
300.3.31
300.3.45 next title omitted and trailing period
300.3.56.

4000. last title

999 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit,
sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat.

Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident,
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 

... followed by arbitrary text, which must not start with (a) digit(s) followed by a period"""

str_list = re.findall(r'''
                           ^       # start of line
                           (?:     # uncaptured ...
                               \d+     # 1 or more decimal digits
                               \.      # period
                           )+      # ... expression, repeated 1 or more times
                           .*?     # minimal number of any characters
                           $       # end of line
                           ^       # start of line
                           .*?     #  minimal number of any characters
                           $       # end of line
                     ''', MyStr, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL | re.VERBOSE)
for s in str_list:
    print(s, end='')
```

Comment: Perfect! This does helps however, what if the chapter title continues on the next line? In this case, looking for the \n\n would be necessary. Any advice?

Comment: @Stijn Van Daele: Do I get it right that the numbered title may take 1 or 2 lines, but is always followed by a blank line?

Comment: I spent some time looking into your code. Your explanation is exquisite.
You have solved the problem!